# Let A1, A2, and A3 be three arbitrary events. Show that the probability that exactly one of these three events will occur is

Tags: probability

Let A1, A2, and A3 be three arbitrary events. Show that
the probability that exactly one of these three events will
occur is

$Pr(A_1) + Pr(A_2) + Pr(A_3)
− 2 Pr(A_1 ∩ A_2) − 2 Pr(A_1 ∩ A_3) − 2 Pr(A_2 ∩ A_3)
+ 3 Pr(A_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ A_3)$

Here's what I was thinking:

$P(A_1∩A_2^c∩A_3^c)+P(A_1^c∩A_2^c∩A_3)+P(A_1^c∩A_2∩A_3^c)$

$P(A_1∩A_2^c∩A_3^c)$
$=P(A_1)∩P(A_2^c)∩P(A_3^c)$
$=P(A_1)P(A_2^c)P(A_3^c)$
$=P(A_1)(1-P(A_2))(1-P(A_3))$
$=P(A_1)(1-P(A_3)-P(A_2)+P(A_3)P(A_2))$
$=P(A_1)-P(A_1)P(A_3)-P(A_1)P(A_2)+P(A_1)P(A_3)P(A_2))$

And likewise for the other two

But my classmate said because it is not independent, I can't replace the intersections with multiplication. So I don't really see how else to solve this

Here is my most recent attempt (along with a venn diagram):
Are my steps in proving the final quantity legitimate/are there any improvements I could make?

$P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2^C\cap \!\,A_3^C)\cup \!\,P(A_1^C\cap \!\,A_2\cap \!\,A_3^C)\cup \!\,P(A_1^C\cap \!\,A_2^C\cap \!\,A_3)$
$=P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2^C\cap \!\,A_3^C)+P(A_1^C\cap \!\,A_2\cap \!\,A_3^C)+P(A_1^C\cap \!\,A_2^C\cap \!\,A_3)$
$=[P(A_1)-[P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2)+P(A_1\cap \!\,A_3)]+P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2\cap \!\,A_3)]+[P(A_2)-[P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2)+P(A_2\cap \!\,A_3)]+P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2\cap \!\,A_3)]+[P(A_3)-[P(A_1\cap \!\,A_3)+P(A_2\cap \!\,A_3)+P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2\cap \!\,A_3)]$
$=P(A_1)-P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2)-P(A_1\cap \!\,A_3)]+P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2\cap \!\,A_3)+P(A_2)-P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2)-P(A_2\cap \!\,A_3)+P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2\cap \!\,A_3)+P(A_3)-P(A_1\cap \!\,A_3)-P(A_2\cap \!\,A_3)+P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2\cap \!\,A_3)$
$=P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)-2P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2)-2P(A_1\cap \!\,A_3)-2P(A_2\cap \!\,A_3)-P(A_2\cap \!\,A_3)+3P(A_1\cap \!\,A_2\cap \!\,A_3)$

Comment: Hint: Let $U$ denote the event that exactly one event from $A_1$, $A_2$, $A_3$ occurs, then the result follows from the algebraic identity $$\mathbf 1_U=\mathbf 1_{A_1}+\mathbf 1_{A_2}+\mathbf 1_{A_3}-2\mathbf 1_{A_1\cap A_2}-2\mathbf 1_{A_2\cap A_3}-2\mathbf 1_{A_3\cap A_1}+3\mathbf 1_{A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3}.$$ Can you show this identity? It may help to consider the counting random variable $S=\mathbf 1_{A_1}+\mathbf 1_{A_2}+\mathbf 1_{A_3}$ and to note that $U=[S=1]$.

Comment: Have you drawn a venn diagram? (This result is a special case of the principle known by the name [inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle))

Comment: @Arthurwould a venn diagram be enough though? I understand hy this is true, but I thought I had to prove it a little more rigorously than just a venn diagram

Comment: I would accept a proof done by venn diagram, provided the different areas are clearly marked. Just because the proof is done by pictures and not words doesn't make it less rigorous. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) for examples.

Comment: @Did I know that identity, but I am not sure how to show that

Comment: If you "know" the algebraic identity in my comment, then integrate it and contemplate the answer to your question. If you want in fact to *prove* the algebraic identity in my comment, then an option is to follow the indication I gave in my comment.