# Probability of exactly $1$ of $3$ events occurring?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem is this:

> Several people, due to a math final the next day, decide to ditch basketball practice. If Lebron, Kobe, and Kawhi have $3/4, 1/3, 1/4$ chance respectively of ditching practice, what is the probability that **exactly one** of the three people ditches practice?

I know these are all independent events and probabilities, but the fact that they are all different probabilities confuses me.

I really see no sensible way to proceed. I know that P(All $3$ ditch) = $1/16$, but see no correlation with the question.

Comment: It should be mentioned in the problem statement that each of the students decisions to skip practice is made *independently* of one another, otherwise there technically isn't enough information to solve.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149757/304620

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** The event that exactly one of the three people ditches has three **disjoint** sub-cases.

- Lebron does, but Kobe and Kawhi do not;
- Kobe does, but Lebron and Kawhi do not;
- Kawhi does, but Lebron and Kobe do not.

Can you compute the probability for each of these three sub-cases?

Answer (score 5):

Yikai has told you the basic way to do it.

An alternative would be to use the probability generating function:

$$\left(\frac14+\frac34x\right)\left(\frac23+\frac13x\right)\left(\frac34+\frac14x\right)$$

whose coefficients, when multiplied out, would give you the probabilities of $0,1,2,3$ people ditching practice